# Dealing with enormous DataFrames - in local environments versus HPC environments

Tags: python, dataframe, recursion, bigdata, hpc

I want to turn a recursive big-data filtering program running on a local environment into a program that can run it's most expensive processes in parallel.

This problem is complex and requires a bit of background information - so please bear with me :) I wrote this in Python 3.7.

I'm using the VIF filtering method from statsmodels.outliers_influence to prune an enormous dataset. Data is tab delimited and I used pandas to load it into a DataFrame.
However, the VIF operation gets extremely expensive as the number of columns and rows in the dataset increase. For math reasons, you can get away with looking at a subset of rows, but all columns need to be considered.
My solution for this was to subset the huge DataFrame into a list of smaller ones, and perform the VIF calculation on each, but there is a trade-off: smaller DataFrames are processed much more quickly but this reduces the accuracy of the overall VIF process (each column only sees what is in it's own subset).
To counteract this, I built a recursive process, involving user-defined values for number of iterations, and had a control flow that went: fragment data --> VIF calculation on fragments --> recombine fragments --> randomize columns --> repeat.
It worked okay ... for a test dataset. About 20 minutes for a single iteration where the original dataset was 600k columns. But even in that test case the # of columns in each fragment was quite small, and I'd imagine I'd want many, many iterations for a higher degree of accuracy.
Therefore, I figured: why not run the VIF process in parallel? So I set out to do just that in an HPC environment. I'm a relatively junior programmer, and I understand that HPC environments can be highly specific/exclusive in their syntax. But the jump to an HPC has complicated my control flow and code to a great extent, involving writing to multiple files in the same directory, calling my script thousands of times (running just one or two methods each time per submitted job), writing, appending to, and sometimes overwriting files each iteration ... it's just insanity. 
I'm having no issues updating the sbash files required to keep the control flow between the project directory, HPC cores, and my script running smoothly; the real rub is getting my script to pull in information, alter it, and write it to a file in a highly specific order based on user input.
If you have experience running scripts in parallel, please lend your advice!

## Here are the methods I used to fragment and filter the data in a local environment:

```
def frag_df(df_snps, og_chunk_delim=len(df_snps.columns) // 15):

    """
    FUNCTION:
    This method takes a DataFrame, evaluates its length, determines a 
    fragmentation size, and separates the DataFrame into chunks. It returns a 
    list of fragmented DataFrames.

    INPUTS:
    df_snps --> A DataFrame object, ideally one pre-processed by df_snps() [an 
    earlier method]

    RETURNS:
    df_list --> a list of fragment DataFrames
    """

    df_list = []
    # Subset df by all SNP predictor columns and find the total number of SNPs 
    in the infile.
    snp_count = len(df_snps.columns)

    # Create counters to be used by an iterative loop (for local 
    applications).

    snp_counter = 0
    fragment_counter = 0
    chunk_delim = og_chunk_delim
    num_chunks = snp_count / chunk_delim
    num_chunks = int(math.ceil(num_chunks))
    print(snp_counter, chunk_delim, num_chunks)

    # Iterate through the snp_count DataFrame and split it into chunks.

    print('\n' 'SNPs fragmenting into list of smaller DataFrames ...' '\n')
    while fragment_counter < num_chunks:
        print('Building Fragment #', fragment_counter + 1, 'from position',
              snp_counter, 'to', chunk_delim)
        df_list.append(df_snps.iloc[:, snp_counter:chunk_delim])

    # Move snp_counter up by specified chunk_delim (Defaults to 50 SNPs).
        snp_counter += og_chunk_delim
        chunk_delim += og_chunk_delim
        fragment_counter += 1
        df_list.append(df_snps.iloc[:, snp_counter:])

        print('\n', 'SNP fragmentation complete. Proceeding to VIF analysis.')

    return df_list

df_list = frag_df(df_snps)
```

```
def vif_calc(df_list, threshold=3.0):

    """
    FUNCTION: This method takes a list of DataFrame objects and conducts VIF 
    analysis on each of them, dropping columns based on some VIF threshold.

    INPUTS:
    df_list --> A list of DataFrame objects processed by frag_df.
    threshold --> The VIF threshold by which columns are to be evaluated.

    RETURNS:
    vif_list --> A list of DataFrames without multicolinear predictor columns.
    """

    df_index = 0
    drop_counter = 0
    filtered_list = df_list
    for df in filtered_list:
        if df.empty:
            del df
    print('\n Iterating through all DataFrames in the passed list.')
    print('\n Dropping columns with a VIF threshold greater than', threshold, 
    '... \n')

        # Create a list of indices corresponding to each column in a given 
        chunk.
        variables = list(range(df.shape[1]))
        df_index += 1
        dropped = True
        try:
            while dropped:
                vif = [variance_inflation_factor(df.iloc[:, variables].values, 
                var) for var in variables]
                if max(vif) < threshold:
                    dropped = False
                    print('\n' 'Fragment #', df_index, 'has been VIF 
                    filtered.','Checking list for next DataFrame ...' '\n')
                    break
                else:
                    max_loc = vif.index(max(vif))
                    if max(vif) > threshold:
                        g = (float("{0:.2f}".format(max(vif))))
                        print('Dropping', df.iloc[:, 
                        variables].columns[max_loc],'at index', str(max_loc + 
                        1), 'within Chunk #', df_index, 'due to VIF of', g)

                        df.drop(df.columns[variables[max_loc]], 1, 
                        inplace=True)
                        variables = list(range(df.shape[1]))
                        dropped = True
                        drop_counter += 1

        except ValueError:
            max_loc = 0

    return filtered_list

filtered_list = vif_calc(df_list, 2.5)
```

## Here's what I used to run my script recursively:

def recursion(remaining, df_shuffled):

```
"""
FUNCTION: This method specifies a number of times to call the other 
methods in the program.

INPUTS:
remaining --> The number of iterations that the user would like to run. 
More iterations = more chances for columns to see other columns.
df_shuffled --> A DataFrame with randomized columns to be used in the 
next iteration of the program.

RETURNS:
df_final --> A DataFrame ready for downstream machine learning analysis.
"""

if remaining == 1:
    print("Recursive VIF filtering complete!", '\n'
    "Here is a preview of your data:", '\n')
    df_final = df_shuffled
    print('\n' 'In this iteration, a total of', col_loss, 'columns were 
    trimmed from the data file.')
    print(df_final.head())
    return df_final

else:
    df_list = frag_df(df_shuffled)
    vif_list = vif_calc(df_list, 2.0)
    print('\n' "All done filtering this iteration! There are", remaining - 
    2, "iterations left.", '\n')
    print('Reconstituting and running next iteration ...')
    df_recon = reconstitute_df(vif_list)
    recursion(remaining - 1, df_recon)
```

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
# All of the above is in working order. Here is the type of output I'd get:

SNPs fragmenting into list of smaller DataFrames ...

Building Fragment # 1 from position 0 to 31
Building Fragment # 2 from position 31 to 62
Building Fragment # 3 from position 62 to 93
Building Fragment # 4 from position 93 to 124
Building Fragment # 5 from position 124 to 155
Building Fragment # 6 from position 155 to 186
Building Fragment # 7 from position 186 to 217
Building Fragment # 8 from position 217 to 248
Building Fragment # 9 from position 248 to 279
Building Fragment # 10 from position 279 to 310
Building Fragment # 11 from position 310 to 341
Building Fragment # 12 from position 341 to 372
Building Fragment # 13 from position 372 to 403
Building Fragment # 14 from position 403 to 434
Building Fragment # 15 from position 434 to 465
Building Fragment # 16 from position 465 to 496

 Iterating through all DataFrames in the passed list.

 Dropping columns with a VIF threshold greater than 2.5 ...

Dropping AGE at index 2 within Chunk # 1 due to VIF of 16.32
Dropping UPSIT at index 2 within Chunk # 1 due to VIF of 7.07
Dropping snp164_C at index 5 within Chunk # 1 due to VIF of 2.74
Dropping snp139_T at index 19 within Chunk # 1 due to VIF of 2.52

Fragment # 1 has been VIF filtered. Checking list for next DataFrame ...

Dropping snp499_C at index 9 within Chunk # 2 due to VIF of 2.81
Dropping snp30_C at index 4 within Chunk # 2 due to VIF of 2.78
Dropping snp424_A at index 29 within Chunk # 2 due to VIF of 2.73
Dropping snp32_C at index 10 within Chunk # 2 due to VIF of 2.53

Fragment # 2 has been VIF filtered. Checking list for next DataFrame ...

Dropping snp483_T at index 31 within Chunk # 3 due to VIF of 2.84
Dropping snp350_T at index 26 within Chunk # 3 due to VIF of 2.6
Dropping snp150_A at index 28 within Chunk # 3 due to VIF of 2.55

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
# When I tried to move to the HPC environment, things got crazy.
I only wanted to have vif_calc() run in parallel; everything else only needed 1 core. So I designed a sort of 'flag' system, and had my methods run only if the flag was set to a certain value. The dilemma was, I had to write the files that called my script using THIS SAME SCRIPT! And even worse, vif_calc() couldn't rely on the script anymore to supply the DataFrame to filter, instead I had to dump the fragments into the working directory. Here's how I set it up:

    def init_pipeline():

        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

        parser.add_argument("datafile", type=str, default='discrete.dataforml',
                            help="Please enter the name of a CSV file to be 
                            processed.")
        parser.add_argument("fragment", type=int, choices=range(50, 300), 
                           default=50, help="DataFrame fragment size. Smaller 
                           fragments processed faster, but require more 
                           iterations.")
        parser.add_argument("-fg", "--flag",  type=int, choices=range(1, 5), 
                           default=1, help="Specify which part of the script to 
                           run this iteration. Defaults to pre-processing.")
        parser.add_argument("-th", "--threshold", type=float, choices=range(2, 6), 
                           default=4.0, help="Specify VIF filtering threshold. 
                           Columns exceeding it will be dropped from the 
                           DataFrame.")
        parser.add_argument("-re", "--recursion", type=int, choices=range(0, 50), 
                           default=0, help="Recursive filtering. Choose # of 
                           iterations from 0 to 50. Default is no recursion.")

        args = parser.parse_args()
        data = args.datafile
        thresh = args.threshold
        recur = args.recursion
        frag = args.fragment
        flag = args.flag

# I passed the arguments into a dictionary so every single time the script was called (once per submitted job), it'd have what it needed.

    arguments = dict([('file', data), ('frag', frag), ('flag', flag), 
    ('vif_threshold', thresh), ('iters', recur)])
    return arguments

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

# Then I ran into many complicated problems. How could I get the fragmented DataFrames to and from files and get different calls to this same script to effectively communicate with one another? Solution was basically: write to other files (master.sh and swarm_iter.txt) to handle the control flow in the HPC environment.

    def frag_df(df_snps, flag, og_chunk_delim=50):

        if flag == 1 or 2:

            df_list = []
            # Subset df by all SNP predictor columns and find the total number of 
            SNPs in the infile.
            snp_count = len(df_snps)
            # Create counters to be used by an iterative loop (for local 
            applications).
            snp_counter = 0
            num_chunks = 1
            chunk_delim = og_chunk_delim
            swarm_counter = 0

            # Iterate through the snp_count DataFrame and split it into chunks.
            print('\n' 'SNPs fragmenting into list of smaller DataFrames ...')
            while chunk_delim + og_chunk_delim <= snp_count:
                df_list.append(df_snps.iloc[:, snp_counter:chunk_delim])
                # print(cov_snps.iloc[:,snp_counter:chunk_delim])
                # Move snp_counter up by specified chunk_delim (Defaults to 50 
                SNPs).
                snp_counter += og_chunk_delim
                chunk_delim += og_chunk_delim
                num_chunks += 1

            print('\n', 'SNP fragmentation complete. Proceeding to VIF analysis.')

            # Now use the fragments in df_list to write/overwrite the .swarm file 
            in the directory.
            # Use the .swarm file to create a series of temporary txt files 
            corresponding to each fragment.
            # These files can be deleted or overwritten after the VIF_filtering 
            process.

            swarm_writer = open('swarm_iter.txt', "w")
            df_list_inc = len(df_list)
            while swarm_counter < df_list_inc:
                if len(df_list) == 0:
                    return df_list
                else:
                    fragment_list = []     # A list containing names of file 
                    objects (each is a txt DataFrame).
                    frag_writer_inc = swarm_counter
                    df_frag_writer = open('df_' + str(frag_writer_inc+1) + '.txt', 
                                     "w")
                    df_frag_writer.write(str(df_list[swarm_counter]))
                    fragment_list.append(str('df_' + str(frag_writer_inc+1) + 
                                        '.txt'))
                    df_frag_writer.close()

                    # Write a line to the swarm file - ensure that flag == 3 so 
                    only vif_calc() is called.

                    for DataFrame in fragment_list:
                        swarm_line = 'python filter_final_swarm.py', DataFrame, 
                                     '50 3 -re 2' '\n'
                        swarm_writer.write(str(swarm_line))
                        swarm_counter += 1
                        swarm_writer.close()

            # Finally, append new lines to master.sh - the swarm command and bash 
            commands used downstream!
            # Ensure that it's dependent on the previous job's completion (in 
            which the flag == 1 or 2).
            job_counter = 1
            master_writer = open('master.sh', "a+")
            swarm_command = str('jobid' + str(job_counter+1) + '=$(swarm -f 
                            swarm_iter.txt --dependancy afterany:$jobid' + 
                            str(job_counter) + '--module python -g 3.0 -b 30)' 
                            '\n')
            nxt_sbash = str('jobid' + str(job_counter+2) + '=$(sbatch -- 
                        dependancy=afterany:$jobid' + str(job_counter+1) + 'python 
                        filter_final_swarm.py 50 4' '\n')
            master_writer.write(swarm_command)
            master_writer.write(nxt_sbash)
            master_writer.close()

``````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

 # So in this version, a list of file names was being passed to vif_calc() instead of a list of DataFrames.

    def vif_calc(comp_df_lists_dict, flag, threshold=5.0):
        if flag == 3:
            df_dir_files = len(fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(r'C:\Users\thomasauw\VIF- 
       Filter-master'), 'df_*'))
            df_index = 0
            drop_counter = 0

            filtered_list = comp_df_lists_dict.get('df_file_list')
            print('\n Iterating through all DataFrames in the passed list.')
            print('\n Dropping columns with a VIF threshold greater than', 
                 threshold, '.''\n')
            for file in filtered_list:
                active_df = open(file, 'r')
                df = pd.read_csv(active_df, sep="\t")

                # Create a list of indices corresponding to each column in a given 
                chunk.
                variables = list(range(df.shape[1]))
                df_index += 1
                dropped = True
                try:
                    while dropped:
                        vif = [variance_inflation_factor(df.iloc[:, 
                              variables].values, var) for var in variables]
                        if max(vif) < threshold:
                            dropped = False

                        # Now the method must overwrite the DataFrames it took in 
                        with FILTERED DataFrames. In this version, the 'list' has 
                        just a single DataFrame element, and the script is taking  
                        in a different file each time (being called many times).

                            filtered_df_frag_writer = open('df_' + str(df_index), 
                            '\n' "w")
                            filtered_df_frag_writer.write(df)
                            filtered_df_frag_writer.close()

                            print('\n' 'Fragment #', df_index, 'has been VIF 
                            filtered. Checking list for next DataFrame ...' '\n')

                            break

                         else:
                            max_loc = vif.index(max(vif))
                            if max(vif) > threshold:
                                g = (float("{0:.2f}".format(max(vif))))
                                print('Dropping', df.iloc[:, 
                                variables].columns[max_loc], 'at index', 
                                str(max_loc + 1), 'within Chunk #', df_index,
                                'due to VIF of', g)

                                df.drop(df.columns[variables[max_loc]], 1, 
                                inplace=True)

                                variables = list(range(df.shape[1]))
                                dropped = True
                                drop_counter += 1

                except ValueError:
                    max_loc = 0

            return filtered_list

        # If the flag requirement isn't met, simply return what was passed as 
        the list of DataFrames when the argument was called in the first place.

        else:
            return comp_df_lists_dict


    vif_list = vif_calc(comp_df_lists_dict, arg_holder.get('flag'), 
                        arg_holder.get('vif_threshold'))

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
What I'm really looking for first and foremost is advice on how to approach this problem. For this specific case though, the error I've run into presently seems to be one with the statsapi VIF method itself. I've succeeded in getting the script to write a master.sh file, a swarm_iter.txt file, and the DataFrame files that vif_calc() needs. All of those files are in the working directory when this command is run:

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

    python filter_final_swarm.py discrete.dataForML 50 -fg 3 -re 2

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

# Then, here is the result (note that with a flag == 3, the earlier methods responsible for fragmenting the data have already done their job. Assume that the HPC environment submitted that job successfully.

`````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

SNPs fragmenting into list of smaller DataFrames ...

 SNP fragmentation complete. Proceeding to VIF analysis.

 Iterating through all DataFrames in the passed list.

 Dropping columns with a VIF threshold greater than 4.0 .

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filter_final_swarm.py", line 315, in <module>
    vif_list = vif_calc(comp_df_lists_dict, arg_holder.get('flag'), arg_holder.get('vif_threshold'))
  File "filter_final_swarm.py", line 270, in vif_calc
    vif = [variance_inflation_factor(df.iloc[:, variables].values, var) for var in variables]
  File "filter_final_swarm.py", line 270, in <listcomp>
    vif = [variance_inflation_factor(df.iloc[:, variables].values, var) for var in variables]
  File "C:\Users\thomasauw\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Py37\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\stats\outliers_influence.py", line 184, in variance_inflation_factor
    r_squared_i = OLS(x_i, x_noti).fit().rsquared
  File "C:\Users\thomasauw\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Py37\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py", line 838, in __init__
    hasconst=hasconst, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\thomasauw\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Py37\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py", line 684, in __init__
    weights=weights, hasconst=hasconst, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\thomasauw\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Py37\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\regression\linear_model.py", line 196, in __init__
    super(RegressionModel, self).__init__(endog, exog, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\thomasauw\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Py37\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py", line 216, in __init__
    super(LikelihoodModel, self).__init__(endog, exog, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\thomasauw\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Py37\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py", line 68, in __init__
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\thomasauw\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Py37\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\model.py", line 91, in _handle_data
    data = handle_data(endog, exog, missing, hasconst, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\thomasauw\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Py37\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\data.py", line 635, in handle_data
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\thomasauw\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Py37\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\data.py", line 80, in __init__
    self._handle_constant(hasconst)
  File "C:\Users\thomasauw\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Py37\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\data.py", line 125, in _handle_constant
    if not np.isfinite(ptp_).all():
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

# I've confirmed that 'df' is a DataFrame object, read in by looking at each 'active_df' file in the working directory in succession, and reading it into 'df'. If I were to continue down this path of insanity (please tell me that isn't the right thing to do here), how would I solve this problem? I'd expect the VIF filter to work normally and overwrite each file in succession (for later recombination/randomization/refragmentation).
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````

Comment: Have you considered [Dask](https://dask.org/)?

Comment: I'm trying to use Dask to solve this problem but there seems to be incompatibility between dd and the vif method from statsapi